# If $\{a_n+ b_n\}$ converges to $A$, and $ \{a_n- b_n\}$ converges to $B$. Show the sequence $\{a_nb_n\}$ converges to $(A^2- B^2)/4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> $\{a_n\} , \{b_n \}$ are two sequences; $\{a_n+ b_n\}$ converges to $A$, and $ \{a_n- b_n\}$ converges to $B$. Show the sequence $\{a_nb_n\}$ converges to $(A^2- B^2)/4$?

I do not need rigorous proof for this query, but I'm not sure which theorem to begin with to analyze the problem. But it's awful late - if anyone could solve this or give me major direction, I would be grateful...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint

$$ab=\frac14((a+b)^2-(a-b)^2)$$

Comment: Hint number two?  :)

Comment: For your question on the odd and  continuous function I gave a complete answer. Isn't it? :-)

Comment: it was a good start, and I needed more precise analysis of the relationship of the epsilon and delta values, but I am happy to thank you there if I can figure out how to find it again

Comment: Thanks. I see the algebra and I added them to get a=(A+B)/2 and I subtracted them to get b=(A-B)/2 and then I multiplied those so that we get the final result. But that is just the algebra. I need some help understanding which sequence and convergence rules allow this.

Comment: Just you need to use the fact that if the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are convergent to $a$ and $b$ then $(a_n+b_n)$ is convergent to $a+b$ and $(a_nb_n)$ is convergent to $ab$.

Comment: I have just stated the addition, subtraction, and multiplication limit laws and proceeded to show the algebra, including the limit notation. Thanks you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.